# Option with title and id

Tags: knockout.js

I'm pushing filtered values of Title and Id to my getItem array:

```
        self.selectItem = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.loanItems(), function(item) {
            if (item.Location() == self.userLocation() && item.LoanItem() == self.selectedLoanType() && item.Status() == "Available") {
                self.getItem.push(item.Title(), item.Id());
                }
            });
        });
```

Then in my view I want to populate my select input, for select I want to show Title and Id as a value:

```
<select data-bind="options: getItem,
                   optionsText: 'Title',
                   optionsValue: 'Id', 
                   optionsCaption: 'Select an item...', 
                   value: selectedLoanTitle">
</select>
```

Above doesn't work, see screen below.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PHOT.png)

Comment: Please show your View Model . need to see how you have getItem set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `options` data-bind you input an (observable) array of items. The `optionsText` and `optionsValue` data-binds refer to property names inside each of these items.

The way you've structured your data-bind requires for the `getItem` array to have items with both an `Id` and `Title` property.

In your `selectItem` method, you call `push` with two parameters, which I'm guessing is where it goes wrong. You're pushing two (supposedly) strings to the array.

Try pushing either:

1. The whole item (`self.getItem.push(item)`), or
2. An object with the required properties (`self.getItem.push({ Title: item.Title, Id: item.Id })`)

Also note that `selectedLoanTitle` will end up having an `Id` property value, not the `Title`...

Comment: Thank you very much, option 2 is exactly what I needed.